# How to auto generate responses for System.out.println

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have two classes. Class A, prompts the user to input a number 9 times using Scanner(System.in). Class B implements class A.

How can I automate responses for class A when running class B. For example, when I run class B, how would I get the computer to respond the number "3" every time class A prompts me to  enter a number?

```
public class A {
     private Scanner scan;

     public A() throws FileNotFoundException{
          scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
               System.out.println("Enter #");
               int num = scan.nextInt();
          }
     }
}
public class B{
     public B(){
          A runA = new A();
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          B runB = new B();
     }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. It is impossible to answer your question correctly without guessing.

Comment: Are you sure that `B` should *implement* (I guess you meant *extends*) class `A`? Does not make much sense to me. Or did you just meant *uses*?

Comment: Are you getting input by using `nextLine()`? Put a `System.out.println("3")` above or below the line that says `Scanner.nextLine()` depending on if you want to display it before, or after the input is given. This has to be done in Class A. If you want it to be done in Class B, you will have to take additional steps. You should provide some code though.

Comment: Fill `System.in` with data from `B`. It may be easier if `A` would not read from `System.in` but via a proxy object you defined. Then you could easily exchange the real source (being it `System.in` or just a custom string for `B`).

Comment: @Kars Writting to `System.out` does not fill `System.in`. As far as I understood, OP wants that his `nextLine` call reads the custom input set from `B`, instead of prompting a user.

Comment: @Zabuza that is my best guess judging him having `System.out.println` in the title.

Comment: @Kars That is exactly what I want: Have the computer fill out the System.out.println() and then use scan.nextInt().

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a function in Class A to get the inputs one by one. Then, from Class B, print the line before the method is called. As such:

```
public class A {

    private Scanner scan;

    public A() throws FileNotFoundException {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void getInput() {
        System.out.println("Enter #");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
    }

}

public class B {

    public B() {

        A runA = new A();

        for(int i=1;i<=9;i++) {
            System.out.println("3");
            runA.getInput();  
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B runB = new B();
    }

}
```

This should be what you want.

Either that or you can print the line above where it says `scan.nextInt();` in your code.